# Cross-stitch image in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

Let's say I have an image called **testimage.jpg**, and want to [cross-stitch it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-stitch) with a DMC 208 floss (RGB value: 148,91,128)

I got these hints:

1. Read each pixel's RGB value
2. Compare it with the floss
3. Use bilinear interpolation for image scaling
4. Use Euclidean distance to get the closest color

I think I already figured out how to do step 1. Now I'm wondering how to do step 2, and 4.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("testimage.jpg"));

int imgWidth = img.getWidth();
int imgHeight = img.getHeight();
Color dmc208 = new Color(148,91,128);
Color currentPixel = null;

for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++){
        currentPixel = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
    }
}
```

I know how to calculate the Eulicdean distance, but how to get the"closest" color at that distance?

Comment: Can you upload the test-image? When I understood you correctly, your cross-stich is going to be two-colored: background-color is the linen mesh and the foreground-color is your floss, right? Btw, the RGB color space is not really good for calculating color distances. You probably want a color-space that is connected to the color-perception of humans.